# Do two things onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having trouble getting the menu to work how I'd like. Basically when you click "Business" or "Personal" I'd like the dropdown menu to become visible, which is working, but then I'd also like for the Downward arrow change to an X. I have the two classes set up properly, one being the arrow and one being the X.

However, I'm struggling to get the dropdown and arrow-to-x change both working. Also, not 100% sure the best way to structure this set up. As you can see below I tried to pull out the business one to see if I could get it to work, but couldn't. It would normally be in the menu like normal and `<DropdownArrowBusiness />` wouldn't be outside the normal menu. Thanks for the help!

```
class DropdownArrowBusiness extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {    
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      condition: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      condition: !this.state.condition
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li className={ this.state.condition ? "downarrow" : "xSymbol" } onClick={ this.handleClick } ><span className="menuDropdownLink" onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Business</span></li>
    )
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super ( props )    
    this.stateBusiness = {
      show : false
    }
    this.toggleBusiness = this.toggleBusiness.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      show : false
    }
    this.togglePersonal = this.togglePersonal.bind(this);
  }

  toggleBusiness = () => {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState({ show: show === "business" ? null : "business" });
  };

  togglePersonal = () => {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState({ show: show === "personal" ? null : "personal" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.topNav} >
        <div className="grid">
          <div className="grid-cell">
            <div className={ styles.logoText }>
              <Link to={'/'}><img className={styles.logo} src="https://example.com/images/logo.png" alt=""/></Link>
            </div>
          </div>  
          <nav>
            <div className="grid-cell">
              <ul className="list-unstyled">
                <li><Link to={'/design'}>About</Link></li>
                <li className="downarrow"><span className="menuDropdownLink" onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Business</span></li>
                <li className="downarrow"><span className="menuDropdownLink" onClick={this.togglePersonal}>Personal</span></li>
                <li><Link to={'/posts'}>Blog</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={'/contact'}>Contact</Link></li>
              </ul>              
            </div> 
          </nav>
          <DropdownArrowBusiness />
        </div>
        {this.state.show === "business" && <BusinessDropdown />}
        {this.state.show === "personal" && <PersonalDropdown />}
      </div>
    )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, there doesn't appear to be anything that's communicating with `<DropdownArrowBusiness/>` to change its overall state, which is why you are not getting the effect you are expecting.

To fix this, you can pass down a `prop` from the parent component `<Header/>` to tell `DropdownArrowBusiness` that the navlist is open. It would be good to pass down, `this.state.show`

So inside your `Header` component do:

```
 <DropdownArrowBusiness show={this.state.show}/>
```

Then in `DropdownArrowBusiness` modify the return piece to this:

```
<li className={ this.props.show ? "downarrow" : "xSymbol" } onClick={ this.handleClick } ><span className="menuDropdownLink" onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Business</span></li>
```